# Cannot loading .jpg from external storage using Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I can load this file with Picasso

```
f = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/
     com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs/1446001605577");
```

But I cannot load this one

```
f = new File("/storage/emulated/0/myImageFiles/Image-1371.jpg");
```

Here is the Picasso code

```
Picasso.with(viewHolder.albumArt.getContext())
        .load(f)
        .into(viewHolder.albumArt);
```

Comment: put debug to check f.exists() before passing it to Picasso.

Comment: @DhavalPatel You are correct. I will check mark your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before passing file to `Picasso` check if [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) [exists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) or not.

```
if(f.exists()){
    Picasso.with(viewHolder.albumArt.getContext())
        .load(f)
        .into(viewHolder.albumArt);
}else{
    // Display default image
    Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.img_default).into(viewHolder.albumArt);
}
```